# Providing input to clipper circuits

Tags: analog

I was reading about diode circuits for clippers
According to my observation, I felt only sinusoidal signals are used to give the input.
So, my question is can any wave,for example, square wave, triangluar wave or spikes be provided as an input?

If yes, how? 
If no, Why?

Comment: A clipper circuit can remove certain portions of an **arbitrary waveform** near the positive or negative peaks or both. (source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipper_(electronics))

Comment: Clipper circuits are often **explained** with sine waves as an input.  A sine is the simplest signal.  It is easier to compare the output to the input when you use a simple input.

Answer (score 0):

The job of an ideal clipper is exactly that: clip. Any voltage exceeding a certain range is "cut back" to that range.

Thus, it doesn't really matter what kind of signal you feed in.

Note that just as any real-world signal, a real-world clipper has imperfections:

**Bandwidth**: If you design a clipping circuit that works well for signals from DC to say 20 kHz, and you feed in 200 MHz, then it's pretty much undefined what will happen. In reality, most systems are low pass filters to a certain degree, but it might very well be that 200 MHz just sees as diode in non-conductive mode as capacitor, and that's not much of a hindrance for high-frequency AC signals, for example!

**Maximum voltage ranges**: If you design a circuit say, based on diodes and low-voltage opamps, and you attach grid voltage, you're going to have a Bad Time<sup>TM</sup>.

Especially the **bandwidth** restriction is an interesting one; the analog bandwidth of a square wave signal is theoretically infinite. In practice, it's not, because that square wave was produced by something that doesn't have infinite bandwidth. The clipper now having its own frequency-dependent behaviour will attenuate different parts of the signal differently, leading to a shape that isn't *quite* rectangular anymore. In reality, that's no problem: the math works out that typically, for not incredibly high frequencies, clipping a square wave just actually yields a square wave with lower amplitude, unless your clipping circuit was designed inappropriately.